# why am i moving faster to the left and very slow to the right in pygame?

Tags: python, windows, pygame

so whenever i move my player to the left i move soo fast but when i move to the right i move very slow, although the speed is the same, i implemented delat time and it still is the same?? here is my code:

```
    if sticky_keys:
            if collide_sides == False:
                if move_left != '':
                    if kb.is_pressed(move_left):
                        rect[0].x -= speed * dt
                if move_right != '':
                    if kb.is_pressed(move_right):
                        rect[0].x += speed * dt 
                if move_up != '':
                    if kb.is_pressed(move_up):
                        rect[0].y -= speed * dt
                if move_down != '':
                    if kb.is_pressed(move_down):
                        rect[0].y += speed * dt
                if jump != '':
                    if jumped:
                        rect[0].y -= jump_velocity
                        jump_velocity -= 1
                        if jump_velocity < - 20:
                            jumped = False
                            jump_velocity = 20
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Pygame doesn't let me use float for rect.move, but I need it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63468413/pygame-doesnt-let-me-use-float-for-rect-move-but-i-need-it/63468637#63468637). Since [`pygame.Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) is supposed to represent an area on the screen, a `pygame.Rect` object can only store integral data.

> The coordinates for Rect objects are all integers. [...]

The fraction part of the movement gets lost when the movement is add to the position of the rectangle. As a result, one moves to the left faster than to the right:

```
int(10 - 1.5) == 8
```

```
int(10 + 1.5) == 11
```

Store the position twice. Once with floating point accuracy in `pos_x` and `pos_y` and in integral in `rect[0]`. Change `pos_x` and `pos_y` and finally update `rect[0]`with the rounded position.

Initialization before the application loop:

```py
pos_x, pos_y = rect[0].topleft
```

In the application loop:

```py
if move_left != '':
    if kb.is_pressed(move_left):
        pos_x -= speed * dt
if move_right != '':
    if kb.is_pressed(move_right):
        pos_x += speed * dt 
if move_up != '':
    if kb.is_pressed(move_up):
        pos_y -= speed * dt
if move_down != '':
    if kb.is_pressed(move_down):
        pos_y += speed * dt
rect[0].topleft = (round(pos_x), round(pos_y))
```

Answer (score 0):

From this code it is hard to tell, however I assume it's a rounding error with pygame.Rect. pygame.Rect can only store int values, but you're most likely providing float values.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).