# Pygame move image in a certain direction

Tags: math, pygame

***The image should move from the top left corner to the bottom right corner. and vice versa.***
This works if the width and height of the screen are the same. If the width is larger, the image lands above the lower right corner

```
def basisfunktion(self,j):
    self.rect.x, x1 = self.li[j] ,self.li[j]        
    self.rect.y, y1 = self.li[j + 2] , self.li[j + 2]
    x2 = self.li[j+1]
    y2 = self.li[j+3]
    self.dx = x2 - x1
    self.dy = y2 - y1
    self.dist = math.sqrt(self.dx * self.dx + self.dy * self.dy)      
    
def update(self):       
    if self.rect.x >= 0 and self.rect.x <= screen_x and self.rect.y >= 0 and self.rect.y <= screen_y:            
       self.rect.x += self.speed *self.dx / self.dist
       self.rect.y += self.speed *self.dy / self.dist
       screen.blit(self.image,(self.rect.x, self.rect.y))
    else:           
       if self.index< (len(self.li)-4):
        self.index += 4
        self.rect.x = -1
        self.rect.y = -1 
        runbaby.basisfunktion(self.index)
```

Comment: What is ```runbaby```?

Comment: It seems you've identified the problem: x and y are update by the same amount at each iteration, instead of being updated with amounts such that dx / dy = width / height.

Comment: When i change self.rect.y in  "self.rect.y +=(screen_x/screen_y) * self.speed *self.dy / self.dist" then the deviation from the corner is even greater.

Comment: `self.rect.y` can only store integers, but not floating point numbers. For this reason, the question is "duplicate". See [Pygame doesn't let me use float for rect.move, but I need it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63468413/pygame-doesnt-let-me-use-float-for-rect-move-but-i-need-it/63468637#63468637). This is exactly your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes you just have to read the documentation. See [Pygame doesn't let me use float for rect.move, but I need it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63468413/pygame-doesnt-let-me-use-float-for-rect-move-but-i-need-it/63468637#63468637)

Since [`pygame.Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) is supposed to represent an area on the screen, a `pygame.Rect` object can only store integral data.

> The coordinates for Rect objects are all integers. [...]

The fraction part of the coordinates gets lost when the new position of the object is assigned to the *Rect* object. If this is done every frame, the position error will accumulate over time.

If you want to store object positions with floating point accuracy, you have to store the location of the object in separate variables respectively attributes and to synchronize the `pygame.Rect` object. [`round`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#round) the coordinates and assign it to the location (e.g. `.topleft`) of the rectangle:

```py
def basisfunktion(self,j):
    self.x, x1 = self.li[j] ,self.li[j]        
    self.y, y1 = self.li[j + 2] , self.li[j + 2]
    self.rect.topleft = round(self.x), round(self.y) 
    x2 = self.li[j+1]
    y2 = self.li[j+3]
    self.dx = x2 - x1
    self.dy = y2 - y1
    self.dist = math.sqrt(self.dx * self.dx + self.dy * self.dy)      
    
def update(self):       
    if self.rect.x >= 0 and self.rect.x <= screen_x and self.rect.y >= 0 and self.rect.y <= screen_y:            
       self.x += self.speed *self.dx / self.dist
       self.y += self.speed *self.dy / self.dist
       screen.blit(self.image,(self.rect.x, self.rect.y))
    else:           
       if self.index< (len(self.li)-4):
        self.index += 4
        self.x = -1
        self.y = -1 
        runbaby.basisfunktion(self.index)   
    self.rect.topleft = round(self.x), round(self.y)
```